# SQL: select a user with entries in ALL of a list of sites

Tags: sql, distinct

If I have a table1 with columns table1.user and table1.site, how can I return a list of distinct users that have access to ALL of a list of sites?

Let me clarify. I could start with the following code:

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT user
    FROM    table1
    WHERE   (site IN ('site1','site2','site3'))
```

Of course, this will display all distinct users that have entries for ANY of the three listed sites. I only want the users who have entries for ALL of the three listed sites.

I feel like there's probably an obvious way to do this, and I'm probably going to feel quite stupid once someone points it out. Still, I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  user
FROM    table1
WHERE   site IN ('site1','site2','site3')
GROUP BY user
HAVING count(*) = 3
```

This assumes that the user cannot be assigned to the same site more than once. If that is not the case, than Gordon's comment holds true, and the having expression must be replaced with `HAVING count(distinct site) = 3`

A more dynamic approach where the sites are only specified once and the count() adjusts automatically could be this:

```
WITH sites (site_name) AS (
   VALUES ('site1'), 
          ('site2'),
          ('site3')
)
SELECT  user
FROM    table1
WHERE   site IN (SELECT site_name FROM sites) 
GROUP BY user
HAVING count(*) = (select count(*) from sites);
```

(This is ANSI SQL, as no DBMS has been specified)

Comment: i assume that count will be dynamic in OPs case. you might need to modify the query to match the user count with count of sites

Comment: The correct having expression is:  HAVING count(distinct site) = 3

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no ..what i was saying is number of sites might be more than 3 ..like `site4, site5,...` OP might just has given example for 3 sites

Comment: @Kshitij: as I said: see my edit. The sites only need to be specified once (in the values clause).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: the distinct is only needed if a user can be assigned to the same site more than once.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i saw that... what i am saying is the sites data might not be master data and might be dynamic populated in table1 which can not be predicted earlier. you will need to do something like `WITH sites (site_name) AS (VALUES (select distinct sites from table1))` if it is possible that is.

Comment: @Kshitij: but that would retrieve the users that are assigned to **all** sites. I don't think that's what the OP wants (btw: the `values` clause is wrong if you use a `select` inside the `with`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's what OP said initially `how can I return a list of distinct users that have access to ALL of a list of sites?` ...or maybe not. I am assuming too much. +1 btw for nice answer.

Comment: @Kshitij: I took "*all sites*" to refer to the three listed in the `IN` condition. Let's see what the OP says.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in most DBMS:

```
select user from table1
where site in ('site1', 'site2', 'site3')
group by user
having count(distinct site) = 3
```

Note that you'll have to match the amount of sites (`3` in this case) with the amount of sites listed in the `in` clause.